# Xampp: How to Make a Clean Uninstall to Get Old MySQL Installation Back?

Tags: mysql, lamp, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have since months a working version of MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I installed Xampp from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) and now my old MySQL installation does not work anymore (e.g.: my existing databases are not visible anymore in MySQL workbench, the password seems to be another one).

How can I get my old version of MySQL working again?

It would be ok, if I loose Xampp.

(I see my databases in the filesystem at: `/var/lib/mysql/` and know that the old MySQL configuration is in `/etc/mysql/`)

I posted this question elsewhere, too.

Comment: Now let me get you, you install XAMPP on top of an existing Mysql install and didn't backup?

Comment: Use that link given and this to see if you can recover your data... and please read very well: https://code.google.com/archive/p/innodb-tools/